# How to stack multiple VegaLite graphs on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, graph, axis-labels, vega-lite

I am trying to recreate a certain graphing tool for my company (I'm an intern getting my BS still). I want to use VegaLite graphs to recreate a graph that is essentially 3 unique graphs stacked directly on top of each other. each graph has its own separate Y axis but they all share the same X axis (time). Right now I have populated 2 graphs but they are side by side. It would be helpful to be pointed in the right direction to figure out how to format the graphs placement so that each graph is directly on top of the each other. like so:

```
Graph1
Graph2
Graph3
```

It would also be helpful to learn how to format the X/Y axis labels and hide/remove the X axis of Graph1 and Graph2.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need a concat as described here. https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/composition.html

Comment: Thank you! that was useful. any idea where I can read about fomatting axis labels or hiding them altogether? also its possible to vconcat graphs that use different dataPoints right?

Comment: All the documentation is on that link. There are dozens of examples for you to examine to do what you need as well as a basic tutorial.